# search all files for a given word

Tags: appcode

I am using appcode to work on an xcode project. How do I search all source files in my project for a given keyword? The keyword need not be a method. Something like:

```
grep keyword *.m *.h
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To perform a search across all the project files in the AppCode use `Edit` | `Find` | **Find in Path**. In the `Text to find` field put your keyword, in the `File mask(s)` field put the extensions **separated by comma**:

[image: Find in Path]

Note that the scope is set to the `Whole project`, you can limit it if needed.

Comment: Works great. I wanted to point that the comma is required to separate multiple file extensions in the File mask(s) textfield. So, if you search in *.m *.h (without the comma), you won't get any results.

Comment: Yes, I've highlighted this part of the answer.